# Python List - For x in list not Passing to loop

Tags: list, python-2.7, foreach, paramiko, enumerate

When I try to do something for each item in a list it doesn't work. In each "sh ip route + `x` + \n" It should be using each item in the list (an IP) in place of `x`.

I even tried printing before and after the actual using of the code in paramiko's channel send to make sure that the variable is passed to x. Yet **each "sh ip route x" command when using x, only uses the first item in the list.**

```
sla_route_ips = ['10.0.0.1', '10.2.0.1', '10.3.0.1', '10.4.0.1', '10.5.0.1']
```

Command:

```
pprint.pprint(sla_route_ips)

for x in sla_route_ips:
    print x
    router_channel.send('sh ip route ' + x + '\n')
    print x
    while not buff.endswith('#'):
        resp = router_channel.recv(999999)
        buff += resp
    print buff
```

Output:

```
C:\Python27\Scripts>buffswith2.py
Enter Full Router ID: Router-VPN
['10.0.0.1', '10.2.0.1', '10.3.0.1', '10.4.0.1', '10.5.0.1']
10.0.0.1
10.0.0.1
sh ip route 10.0.0.1
Routing entry for 10.0.0.0/24
  Known via "bgp 1976", distance 200, metric 0, type internal
  Last update from 10.8.111.17 2w6d ago
  Routing Descriptor Blocks:
  * 10.8.111.17, from 10.8.0.1, 2w6d ago
      Route metric is 0, traffic share count is 1
      AS Hops 0

Router-VPN#
10.2.0.1
10.2.0.1
sh ip route 10.0.0.1
Routing entry for 10.0.0.0/24
  Known via "bgp 1976", distance 200, metric 0, type internal
  Last update from 10.8.111.17 2w6d ago
  Routing Descriptor Blocks:
  * 10.8.111.17, from 10.8.0.1, 2w6d ago
      Route metric is 0, traffic share count is 1
      AS Hops 0

Router-VPN#
10.3.0.1
10.3.0.1
sh ip route 10.0.0.1
Routing entry for 10.0.0.0/24
  Known via "bgp 1976", distance 200, metric 0, type internal
  Last update from 10.8.111.17 2w6d ago
  Routing Descriptor Blocks:
  * 10.8.111.17, from 10.8.0.1, 2w6d ago
      Route metric is 0, traffic share count is 1
      AS Hops 0

Router-VPN#
10.4.0.1
10.4.0.1
sh ip route 10.0.0.1
Routing entry for 10.0.0.0/24
  Known via "bgp 1976", distance 200, metric 0, type internal
  Last update from 10.8.111.17 2w6d ago
  Routing Descriptor Blocks:
  * 10.8.111.17, from 10.8.0.1, 2w6d ago
      Route metric is 0, traffic share count is 1
      AS Hops 0

Router-VPN#
10.5.0.1
10.5.0.1
sh ip route 10.0.0.1
Routing entry for 10.0.0.0/24
  Known via "bgp 1976", distance 200, metric 0, type internal
  Last update from 10.8.111.17 2w6d ago
  Routing Descriptor Blocks:
  * 10.8.111.17, from 10.8.0.1, 2w6d ago
      Route metric is 0, traffic share count is 1
      AS Hops 0

Router-VPN#
```

**Desired Output:**

```
C:\Python27\Scripts>buffswith2.py
Enter Full Router ID: Router-VPN
['10.0.0.1', '10.2.0.1', '10.3.0.1', '10.4.0.1', '10.5.0.1']
10.0.0.1
10.0.0.1
sh ip route 10.0.0.1
Routing entry for 10.0.0.0/24
  Known via "bgp 1976", distance 200, metric 0, type internal
  Last update from 10.8.111.17 2w6d ago
  Routing Descriptor Blocks:
  * 10.8.111.17, from 10.8.0.1, 2w6d ago
      Route metric is 0, traffic share count is 1
      AS Hops 0

Router-VPN#
10.2.0.1
10.2.0.1
sh ip route 10.2.0.1
Routing entry for 10.2.0.0/24
  Known via "bgp 1976", distance 200, metric 0, type internal
  Last update from 10.8.111.17 2w6d ago
  Routing Descriptor Blocks:
  * 10.8.111.17, from 10.8.0.1, 2w6d ago
      Route metric is 0, traffic share count is 1
      AS Hops 0

Router-VPN#
10.3.0.1
10.3.0.1
sh ip route 10.3.0.1
Routing entry for 10.3.0.0/24
  Known via "bgp 1976", distance 200, metric 0, type internal
  Last update from 10.8.111.17 2w6d ago
  Routing Descriptor Blocks:
  * 10.8.111.17, from 10.8.0.1, 2w6d ago
      Route metric is 0, traffic share count is 1
      AS Hops 0

Router-VPN#
10.4.0.1
10.4.0.1
sh ip route 10.4.0.1
Routing entry for 10.4.0.0/24
  Known via "bgp 1976", distance 200, metric 0, type internal
  Last update from 10.8.111.17 2w6d ago
  Routing Descriptor Blocks:
  * 10.8.111.17, from 10.8.0.1, 2w6d ago
      Route metric is 0, traffic share count is 1
      AS Hops 0

Router-VPN#
10.5.0.1
10.5.0.1
sh ip route 10.5.0.1
Routing entry for 10.5.0.0/24
  Known via "bgp 1976", distance 200, metric 0, type internal
  Last update from 10.8.111.17 2w6d ago
  Routing Descriptor Blocks:
  * 10.8.111.17, from 10.8.0.1, 2w6d ago
      Route metric is 0, traffic share count is 1
      AS Hops 0

Router-VPN#
```

**UPDATE:**

Running the command with it OUTSIDE of the paramiko `router_channel.send()` creates the desired output for the commands.

Command:

```
for x in sla_route_ips:
    print x
    print 'sh ip route ' + x 
    print x

C:\Python27\Scripts>buffswith2.py
Enter Full Router ID: Router-VPN
['10.0.0.1', '10.2.0.1', '10.3.0.1', '10.4.0.1', '10.5.0.1']
sh ip route 10.0.0.1
sh ip route 10.2.0.1
sh ip route 10.3.0.1
sh ip route 10.4.0.1
sh ip route 10.5.0.1
```

This tells me their is some type of error in handing off the command to Paramiko.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python list iteration works fine.  Your problem is that you do not reset variable `buff` before you try to read back the router response.  As a result, your program never reads the second and subsequent responses because `buff` already satisfies the condition of the inner loop.  The first response is simply output again.